# PHP: ez Component chart does not display

Tags: php, codeigniter, svg, mozilla

I'm using ez Components to draw a simple Pie chart. To test it, I just copy-pasted code from their tutorial to display the chart, but only a blank screen is displayed.

Is it an issue related to SVG rendering by any chance ? Or is there any setting /configuration related to ez Components ? I'm using Mozilla btw.

Code:

```
    <?php

require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries\ezcomponents-2009.2.1\Graph\docs\tutorial\tutorial_autoload.php' );

    class abc extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('abc_model', 'abcModel');
    }

    function index($a="", $b="", $c="", $d="")
    {

    //
    //...some code later
    //...

    // Create a new pie chart
       $chart = new ezcGraphPieChart();

       //echo ('Test');

    $graph = new ezcGraphPieChart();
    $graph->title = 'Access statistics';
    $graph->data['Access statistics'] = new ezcGraphArrayDataSet( array(
    'Mozilla' => 19113,
    'Explorer' => 10917,
    'Opera' => 1464,
    'Safari' => 652,
    'Konqueror' => 474,
    ) );
    $graph->data['Access statistics']->highlight['Mozilla'] = true;
    $graph->render( 400, 150, 'tutorial_simple_pie.svg' ); 



  }

//..some code later
//..

}
```

EDITED LATER:

This is the Error Log from XAMPP, if it helps:

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:37.046875 2014] [core:warn] [pid 4816:tid 168] AH00098: pid file D:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:37.156250 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 4816:tid 168] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:37.640625 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4816:tid 168] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:37.640625 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4816:tid 168] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:37.640625 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4816:tid 168] AH00094: Command line: 'd:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d D:/xampp/apache'

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:37.640625 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4816:tid 168] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6072

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:38.812500 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6072:tid 1884] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]

[Wed Sep 03 15:59:38.906250 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6072:tid 1884] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: blank? try turn on error_reporting and what u seen tell me

Comment: I added the output of the Error log in my original post.

Comment: OK. I used renderToOutput() in the last line, but still nothing displays. Does ez Component even display in an HTML page ? Is there any keyword or setting I must use?

Comment: Finally, I decided to use another charting library.